# Div shrink to wrap issues on width of absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues making the contents of `#div_b` stretch up to a width of 300px.  It remains scrunched up no matter how I modify the CSS.  (Please don't ask me why i'm using absolutes in the outer and inner div because there is a reason I am doing this which I don't want to expand on because this question is not about that problem)

**CSS**

```
#div_a{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  max-width:300px
}

#div_b{
  position: absolute;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div_a">
  <div id="div_b">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est tristique ligula odio semper inceptos ut
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRkCU/1/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of different solutions.

Remove max:
http://jsfiddle.net/BRkCU/12/

Remove Position:
http://jsfiddle.net/BRkCU/15/

Comment: When you say that div_b should have an absolute position the width of div_b will no longer expand the width of div_a.

Answer (score 1):

```
#div_b{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

remove the position: absloute;

```
#div_b{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Notice the gray background is gone and text is still scruntched up.  http://jsfiddle.net/BRkCU/13/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
#div_b{
  position: absolute;
  background-color:gray;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
#div_a{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  max-width:300px;
  width:100%;
}

#div_b{
   position: absolute;
   background-color:gray;
}
```

The reason div_b does not expand is because div_a does not expand. By setting it to 100% you are now taking up as much space as required by the contents and by keeping max-width:300px the content will not go beyond that area.